# Not able to get ng-bind-html to work

Tags: html, angularjs, ngsanitize

**Problem:** I am trying to use ng-bind-html but I am getting the following errors on the console:

[image]

The following is the controller where I am calling ngSanitize:

[image]

and using the following file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

In my form, I do the following to use ng-bind-html. So when I try to see my results, it is still rendering the `&amp;`rather then &:

```
<div ng-bind-html="e.Specialty"></div>
```

and the following is what occurs in the Specialty:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

@lealceldeiro: Here is the controller in which I am trying to implement your suggestion but not sure where I will add it:

```
(
function(){
    var $scope, $location;
    var indexApp = angular.module('indexApp',['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);

    indexApp.controller('IndexController',function($scope,$sce,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
        $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
        $scope.ShowResults = false;
        $scope.ShowDesc = true;
        $scope.NoResults = false;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
        $scope.formModel = {};
        $scope.searchMode = 0;
        $scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
        $scope.Specialties = [{'value':'Family practice'},{'value':'General practice'},{'value':'Internal medicine'},{'value':'Pediatrics'}];
        $scope.Gender = [{'value':'Male'},{'value':'Female'}];
        $scope.Languages = {};
        $scope.Cities = {};
        //$scope.lastAction = '';
        $scope.searchParam = {};
        $("input").removeAttr('disabled');

        $scope.searchParam.Distance = $scope.miles[0];

        $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
            try{
                var lon, lat;
                // console.log('starting geoposition code.');
                if("geolocation" in navigator){
                    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                        lat = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
                        lon = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
                        // console.log(lat + ' ' + lon);
                        $http.get("/Brokers-en-us/includes/remote/ReturnCurrentZipcode.cfm?Lat=" + lat + "&Lon=" + lon)
                        .then(function(response){
                            $scope.searchParam.Zip = response.data;
                        })
                    })
                }
                else{ console.log('No geolocation'); }
            }
            catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
        }

        $scope.GetCityList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/Brokers-en-us/includes/remote/ReturnCityList.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.Cities = response.data.Cities;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.GetLangList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/Brokers-en-us/includes/remote/ReturnLangList.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.Languages = response.data.Languages;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.SearchProvider = function(searchParam){
            try{
                //debugger;
                $scope.searchMode = 1;
                var queryString='';
                if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
                    $scope.resultsCount = 0;
                    currentPage = 1;
                }
                if(searchParam){
                    //debugger;
                    $scope.formModel = searchParam;
                    for(var param in searchParam){
                        if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
                            var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value : searchParam[param];
                            if (paramValue.length > 0)
                                queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(queryString);
                queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;

                $http.get("/Brokers-en-us/includes/remote/ReturnProvidersList.cfm" + queryString)
                .then(function(response){
                    $scope.providers = response.data.provider;
                    $scope.resultsCount = response.data.rowCount;
                    if (!$scope.providers){
                            $scope.NoResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                    else{
                            $scope.NoResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                })
            }
            catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
        }

        /*Testing purposes*/
        $scope.clearTopForm = function(searchParam){
            //console.log("I clicked this.")
        }

        /*Clears the drop downs and input fields*/
        $scope.$watch('searchParam.Distance', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            //debugger;
                    if(newValue != ''){
                        //$scope.lastAction = 'miles';
                        $scope.searchParam.City = '';
                        $scope.searchParam.Specialty = '';
                        $scope.searchParam.Gender = '';
                    }
        });

        $scope.$watch('searchParam.Zip', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if(newValue != ''){
                        //$scope.lastAction = 'miles';
                        $scope.searchParam.Gender = '';
                        $scope.searchParam.Specialty = '';
                        $scope.searchParam.City = '';
                    }
        });

        $scope.cityChange = function(){
            //debugger;
            if($scope.searchParam.City != ''){
                //$scope.lastAction = 'city';
                $scope.searchParam.Distance = '';
                $scope.searchParam.Zip = '';
            }
        }

        $scope.specialtyChange = function(){
            //debugger;
            if($scope.searchParam.Specialty != ''){
                //$scope.lastAction = 'specialty';
                $scope.searchParam.Distance = '';
                $scope.searchParam.Zip = '';
            }
        }

        $scope.genderChange = function(){
            //debugger;
            if($scope.searchParam.Gender != ''){
                //$scope.lastAction = 'gender';
                $scope.searchParam.Distance = '';
                $scope.searchParam.Zip = '';
            }
        }

        $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage'], function(){
            try{
                if($scope.searchMode == 1){
                    $scope.SearchProvider($scope.formModel);
                    }
            }
            catch(err){}
        });


        $scope.GetCityList();
        $scope.GetLangList();
        $scope.GetCurrentZip();

        $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
            //http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/
              // set the location.hash to the id of
              // the element you wish to scroll to.

            //$location.hash('bottom');

              // call $anchorScroll()
            var browserWidth = screen.availWidth;
            if (browserWidth < 768)
                anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);
        };

    });

    indexApp.service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){
        this.scrollTo = function(eID) {

            // This scrolling function 
            // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

            var startY = currentYPosition();
            var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
            var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
            if (distance < 100) {
                scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
            }
            var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
            if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
            var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
            var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
            var timer = 0;
            if (stopY > startY) {
                for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
                    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                    leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
                } return;
            }
            for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
            }

            function currentYPosition() {
                // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
                // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                    return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
                if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
                return 0;
            }

            function elmYPosition(eID) {
                var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
                var y = elm.offsetTop;
                var node = elm;
                while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                    node = node.offsetParent;
                    y += node.offsetTop;
                } return y;
            }

        };

    });

    indexApp.directive('allowPattern',[allowPatternDirective]);
    indexApp.directive('popPopup',[describePopup]);
    indexApp.directive('pop', function pop ($tooltip, $timeout) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('pop', 'pop', 'event');
    var compile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);
    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {      
      var first = true;
      attrs.$observe('popShow', function (val) {
        if (JSON.parse(!first || val || false)) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.triggerHandler('event');
            });
            }
            first = false;
        });
        return compile(element, attrs);
        };
        return tooltip;
    });

    indexApp.filter('PhoneNumber', function(){
    return function(phoneNumber){
        var dash = '-';
        var openParen = '(';
        var closeParen = ') ';
        if(phoneNumber){
            var pn = phoneNumber;
            pn = [pn.slice(0, 6), dash, pn.slice(6)].join('');
            pn = openParen + [pn.slice(0, 3), closeParen, pn.slice(3)].join('');
            return pn;
            }
        return phoneNumber;
        }
    });

    indexApp.filter('Zip', function(){
    return function(zipcode){
        var dash = '-';
        if(zipcode && zipcode.length > 5){
            var zc = zipcode;
            zc = [zc.slice(0, 5), dash, zc.slice(5)].join('');
            return zc;
            }
        return zipcode;
        }
    });

    function allowPatternDirective(){
        return{
            restrict: "A",
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
                return function(scope, element, attrs){
                    element.bind("keypress", function(event){
                        var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
                        var keyCodeChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

                        if(!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function describePopup(){
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
            templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
            };
        }
})();
(function($) {
  // @todo Document this.
  $.extend($,{ placeholder: {
      browser_supported: function() {
        return this._supported !== undefined ?
          this._supported :
          ( this._supported = !!('placeholder' in $('<input type="text">')[0]) );
      },
      shim: function(opts) {
        var config = {
          color: '#888',
          cls: 'placeholder',
          selector: 'input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]'
        };
        $.extend(config,opts);
        return !this.browser_supported() && $(config.selector)._placeholder_shim(config);
      }
  }});

  $.extend($.fn,{
    _placeholder_shim: function(config) {
      function calcPositionCss(target)
      {
        var op = $(target).offsetParent().offset();
        var ot = $(target).offset();

        return {
          top: ot.top - op.top,
          left: ot.left - op.left,
          width: $(target).width()
        };
      }
      function adjustToResizing(label) {
        var $target = label.data('target');
        if(typeof $target !== "undefined") {
          label.css(calcPositionCss($target));
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(label); });
        }
      }
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.is(':visible') ) {

          if( $this.data('placeholder') ) {
            var $ol = $this.data('placeholder');
            $ol.css(calcPositionCss($this));
            return true;
          }

          var possible_line_height = {};
          if( !$this.is('textarea') && $this.css('height') != 'auto') {
            possible_line_height = { lineHeight: $this.css('height'), whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };
          }

          var isBorderBox = ($this.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box');
          var isTextarea = $this.is('textarea');

          var ol = $('<label />')
            .text($this.attr('placeholder'))
            .addClass(config.cls)
            .css($.extend({
              position:'absolute',
              display: 'inline',
              'float':'none',
              overflow:'hidden',
              textAlign: 'left',
              color: config.color,
              cursor: 'text',
              paddingTop: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-top'),
              paddingRight: $this.css('padding-right'),
              paddingBottom: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-bottom'),
              paddingLeft: $this.css('padding-left'),
              fontSize: $this.css('font-size'),
              fontFamily: $this.css('font-family'),
              fontStyle: $this.css('font-style'),
              fontWeight: $this.css('font-weight'),
              textTransform: $this.css('text-transform'),
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              zIndex: 99,
            }, possible_line_height))
            .css(calcPositionCss(this))
            .attr('for', this.id)
            .data('target',$this)
            .click(function(){
                if (!$(this).data('target').is(':disabled')) {
                    $(this).data('target').focus();
                }
            })
            .insertBefore(this);
            $this
                .data('placeholder', ol)
                .on('keydown', function () {
                    ol.hide();
                })
                .on('blur change', function () {
                    ol[$this.val().length ? 'hide' : 'show']();
                })
                .triggerHandler('blur');
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(ol); });
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).add(window).bind('ready load', function() {
  if (jQuery.placeholder) {
    jQuery.placeholder.shim();
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `e.Specialty`?, I don't see it in the code (image)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147127/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-minerr-of-undefined)

Comment: have you used `$sce.trustAsHtml(value)`?

Comment: @lealceldeiro: it holds doctors specialty (ex. audiology, etc.)

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii: I have not. How does that work and where would that go?

Comment: @Robert Just a guess, inject `$sce` service and pass your html to that method, see if it works.

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii I  have injected $sce in the controller and not sure what method you speak of

Comment: `trustAsHtml(value)`

Comment: @lealceldeiro: I also tried the possible duplicate and it still does not render the ampersand correctly and still not getting it. sorry

Comment: Robert, I checked your updated question. See my answer below with details. @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii was right about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), AngularJS sometimes consider some contents as unsafe (as your case), so you need to use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service in order to "mark" this content as safe (to be used) like this:

`$sce.trustAsHtml("CLINICAL &amp; SOCIAL");` (See demo below)

From [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

> The input is sanitized by parsing the HTML into tokens. All safe
>   tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to properly escaped
>   html string. This means that **no unsafe input can make it into the
>   returned string**.

In this case the "unsafe" part is `&amp;`

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ctrl);

function ctrl($scope, $sce) {
$scope.Specialty = $sce.trustAsHtml("CLINICAL &amp; SOCIAL");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

Specialty: <span ng-bind-html="Specialty"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: @ lealceldeiro: Where woulld I add the $scope. The reason I am asking specialty is being called from a cfm which calls the database to display the results. I have posted the controller

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your question or not, but: wherever you set `specialty` you have to do it like this `$sce.trustAsHtml(specialtyVal);` where `specialtyVal` can be anything, a var value, a value coming from database, and so on. The result of calling the `trustAsHtml` function is a content that you can safely use with `ng-bind-html`. Where should you use it? My suggestion is: in the controller. Get any necessary data in services, call services functions on controllers, and then use the `trustAsHtml` function to prepare the string to be rendered on the view. Hope it helps